# Notation Question : $i(n,k)$ denote the number of permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ with $i(\sigma) = k$

Tags: notation

Notation Question :

Below is the excerpt from a textbook :

**$i(n,k)$ denote the number of permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ with $i(\sigma) = k$ that is $k$ inversions.**

from the above statement which set does $S_n$ denote for?

[edit: additional question]

In following statement, What exactly does LHS mean?

$\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} i(\sigma) = {n!\over 2} \binom{n}{2}$

Comment: $S_n$ denotes the group of permutation of the set $\left\{1,2,3,...,n\right\}$. Probably.

Comment: @Hellen or, would it be more plausible to understand $S_n$ denotes every sequences made from $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$?

Comment: $\sigma$ in that sentence is being called a permutation. Permutations are bijective functions from $\left\{1,2,...,n \right\}$ to $\left\{1,2,...,n \right\}$.

Comment: Perhaps some some books or you would like to call that a sequence, but it is more common to call sequence to a function, not necessarily bijective from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\left\{1,2,...,n \right\}$.

Comment: @Hellen I had added one more additional edit to the OP. Could you give me some advice about what LHS denote for?

Comment: The sum of $i(\sigma)$ when $\sigma$ ranges over all $n!$ permutations of the set $\left\{1,2,...,n\right\}$. From the sentence in your question it looks like $i(\sigma)$ is defined to be the smallest number of inversions (permutations that only change the position of two elements) required to obtain $\sigma$.